# Change characters in sql file

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, utf8-decode

I have some questions about MySQL and characters on `.sql files`.

I picked up a module for an accounting software (Dolibarr if some people know it) and I get a problem with an `.sql file`.

This file looks like :

[image]

I get this character [image] instead of getting french accent character like "é" "è" "ô" etc ...

My question is :

I assume that it's a character set problem. It's unicode and I need utf-8 ?
If it's the truth, how I can change that ?
Because in this file, there's not define something like :

```
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

And I don't know how this .sql file is called by the MySQL database, so it's maybe a database problem ? :/

Thank you to your answers, and your script if you could help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open your file in an any editor capable of Reading the encoding you have in your file and then save the file in the desired encoding.

Comment: Ok I gonna make this and I will come back if it works or if I get some problems ;)

Comment: It works :) I opened my sql file with notepad and I changed to utf-8. Then I renamed it to .sql and accents are still there !